# How to use framework7 preloader inside a function

Tags: phonegap, html-framework-7

**I have this simple login function and I want to add a preloader, after trying what's in their doc I can't make the preloader show any tips why? http://v2.framework7.io/docs/preloader.html source.**

```
$$('.button-login').on('click', function (e) {
            app.preloader.show();
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
            if(username != '' && password !='' ){
            app.request({ 
                url: 'https://server/login',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    'username': username,
                    'password': password
                        }),
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                crossDomain: true,
                headers: {'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)},
            error: function (data) {
              app.preloader.hide();
              app.dialog.alert('Invalid username or password!', 'Login Error');
            },

            success: function (data)  {
                app.dialog.alert('Welcome ' + username, 'Login Success');
                localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
                localStorage.setItem('authorization', 'Basic' + btoa(username + ':' +password));
                localStorage.setItem('username', username);
                app.preloader.hide();
                app.loginScreen.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you used `var app = new Framework7();` to define `app`?
Is there some errors in console?

I made jsfiddle for you. Check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s6ydogmu/).

If you want to hide preloader overlay after ajax call use dom7:  `$$('.preloader').hide();`

Comment: yes apparently there's no error in console. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Your example are still based from the docs and still does not show any preloader. Your answer is acceptable but I does not fixed my problem.

Comment: @jamesbondo yeah, my example is based from docs, that's only way you can make something. Its so simple, take a look https://jsfiddle.net/s6ydogmu/

Comment: @jamesbondo just do not forget `<div class="preloader"></div>` where preloader will show.

Comment: @jamesbondo Does it work for you? Instead of alert in jsfidle above you can set timeout for few seconds to show preloader

Comment: Thanks man, I don't know what happened but it works now. I still use the code above.